# Rolling numbering of data in a view

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am using the following query to number the data based on parameter a and b.

```
count(table.a) OVER (PARTITION BY table.b, tdahw.a ORDER BY table.date) AS row_count
```

The output is numbering the values as incremental.
However, if there are 3 counts of a over partition of a and b, I want it to display 3 across all the rows. What tweaks should I make to the existing thing?

Sample data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arn6Z.png)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: I gather that column `a` is nullable? If it isn't, then your `count(table.a)` is the same as `row_number()` and you can just replace that by `rank()` or `dense_rank()`. If it is, then explicitly use a `RANGE` clause in your window expression (rather than the default `ROWS` clause):

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I have attached a sample file

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Pls refer to sample file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove order by :

```
select count(m.a) OVER (PARTITION BY m.b, m.a) AS row_count 
from mytable m
```

Here is a simple demo I created:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2a484e830275c0ae77fa49ba57e9436c)

So for you it would be :

```
count(table.a) OVER (PARTITION BY table.b, tdahw.a) AS row_count
```